# repository problem after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: repository, 22.04, software-sources

I upgraded from 20.04 (focal) to 22.04 (jammy) and in the `sources.list.d` folder it is still showing some files with focal in them. Should I change them to jammy manually?

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal main
```

Comment: Please change the image to text. Images can not be searched from and I had to retype your url instead of copy/pasteing it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

General advice:

First you need to check if that repository has a version for jammy.
If there is you can change it. if there is not you have two options: remove the software or stick with the version for focal.

Specific to git-core:

See Url is [https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egit-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) It has a jammy and already a kinetic so yes, go ahead. Do not forget to relead the sources.

Mind that the file name also has focal in the name.

Comment: so i will have to change the file name as well?

Comment: It is advised to do so yes.

Answer (score 3):

ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa  currently publishes packages for Ubuntu 22.04. Please change `focal` to `jammy` in `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa focal main`and `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa focal main`. Then run `sudo apt update`

If the current name of the file in `/etc/apt/sources.d/` directory is *git-core-ubuntu-ppa-**focal**.list* then change its name to *git-core-ubuntu-ppa-**jammy**.list* by running the following commands:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.d/
sudo mv git-core-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list git-core-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
sudo apt update
```